# Angularjs Post call to spring boot

Tags: angularjs, spring-boot, jhipster

I am new to Spring MVC, I am building an With angularjs and Spring Boot.

When i tried to make POST call through angularjs, i am getting this error.
But when i tried with the postman it is working with x-www-form-urlencoded but with form-data i am getting the below error.

**Post Man Error**

```js
{
  "timestamp": 1491406541851,
  "status": 500,
  "error": "Internal Server Error",
  "exception": "org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException",
  "message": "PreparedStatementCallback; SQL [INSERT INTO employeedetails(Name, Company, Location,Age) VALUES (?,?,?,?)]; Column 'Name' cannot be null; nested exception is com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Column 'Name' cannot be null",
  "path": "/createEmployee"
}
```

**HTTP call in Angularjs**

```html
$http({
      method: 'POST',
      url: "/createEmployee",
      headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
      data: $scope.employee,
  }).success(function () {});
```

```js
 
 @RequestMapping(value="/createEmployee", method=RequestMethod.POST,consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE)
 public void createEmployee( employeeDetails empl)
 {
  System.out.println(empl.getAge());
  empdao.createEmployee(empl);
 }
```

Comment: Because in your spring api you are accepting media type 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' not 'form data'. If you want it to send as form data, then you need to change your spring API.

Comment: can you give me the code to be changed

Comment: In which type, you want to send data?? 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' or 'form-data'??

Comment: in form-data i like to give ..

Answer (score 0):

```
@RequestMapping(value="/createEmployee", method=RequestMethod.POST,consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE)
public void createEmployee(@RequestBody @Valid  employeeDetails empl)
{
    System.out.println(empl.getAge());
    empdao.createEmployee(empl);
}
```

Comment: Please edit your answer to include some explanation. Code-only answers do very little to educate future SO readers. Your answer may end up in the moderation queue for being low-quality.